# MS Chart customize value label and draw Line series across the chart area

Tags: c#, vb.net, charts, data-visualization, mschart

**I'd like to get suggestion in both C# and VB.NET**

I created Chart like the following image:

[image]

1. How can I customize the value on the
   top of each column from code-behind?
   Instead of showing 21, 49, 19 I'd
   like to show 21 hr, 49 hr, 19 hr
2. How can I show the those values on
   top of other lines? As you can see
   19 is below the Line series.
3. Can I set draw the line across the
   Chart Area not just across the
   column? So, the line will start from
   Axis X to end of the Chart Area.

Here's the mark-up:

```
 <asp:chart id="Chart1" runat="server" Height="296px" Width="500" ImageLocation="~/TempChartFiles/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" Palette="BrightPastel" imagetype="Png" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BackSecondaryColor="White" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BorderWidth="2" backcolor="#D3DFF0" BorderColor="26, 59, 105">
                    <legends>
                        <asp:Legend IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" BackColor="Transparent" Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"></asp:Legend>
                    </legends>
                    <borderskin skinstyle="Emboss"></borderskin>
                    <series>
                        <asp:Series Name="Month" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" IsValueShownAsLabel="true">
                        </asp:Series>
                    </series>
                    <chartareas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BackSecondaryColor="White" BackColor="64, 165, 191, 228" ShadowColor="Transparent" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom">
                            <area3dstyle Rotation="10" perspective="10" Inclination="15" IsRightAngleAxes="False" wallwidth="0" IsClustered="False"></area3dstyle>
                            <axisy linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64">
                                <labelstyle font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                                <majorgrid linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                            </axisy>
                            <axisx linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64">
                                <labelstyle font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                                <majorgrid linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                            </axisx>
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </chartareas>
                </asp:chart>
```

Here's the code-behind:

Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Interval = 1

```
    ' Create new data series and set its visual attributes
    Dim series As New Series("Minimum Hour")

    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    series.BorderWidth = 2
    series.ShadowOffset = 1
    series.AxisLabel = 0


    Dim monthyHour = 22
    series.Name = "Min. Hour : " & monthyHour

    Dim xValue() As String = {"Jun", "Jul", "Aug"}
    Dim yValue() As Integer = {21, 49, 19}

    'add value for Line series
    For i = 0 To xValue.Length - 1 Step 1

         series.Points.AddY(monthyHour)

    Next

    Chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(xValue, yValue)

    ' Add series into the chart's series collection
    Chart1.Series.Add(Series)
```

Comment: For #1 question. You could try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.textannotation.text.aspx this. I'm not sure. But, could be helpful. Best advice is to go through the UI di-sected image architecture of the chart control. Which will look something like this http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/designing-your-first-pivottable-pivotchart-views-in-access-HA001034580.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

To add it from code behind you need to set Chart1.Series(0).Label=monthyHour +"Hrs"